# How to fix Interface 'QuerySnapshot<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData> in firebase & Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I installed latest version of `@angular/fire` but getting lot of unexpected error. If anyone know the solution of this. Please let me know.

> node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'DocumentSnapshotExists' incorrectly extends interface 'DocumentSnapshot'.
> The types returned by 'data(...)' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData | undefined'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

> 13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
> 13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
> ~
> This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData` constraint.
> node_modules/@angular/fire/compat/firestore/interfaces.d.ts:13:41
> 13 export interface DocumentSnapshotExists extends firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot {
> ~
> This type parameter might need an `extends firebase.firestore.DocumentData | undefined` constraint.

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

there is mismatch between firebase and angular/fire
try to install both latest versions

```
npm install firebase@latest @angular/fire@latest
```

Comment: I already installed latest version of both libraries. But error is still coming.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and here is what worked for me. the commented lines have been replaced by those below. for more detail I suggest [this github link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3255)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35834333)